# How to select printer for FlowDocument in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to print a FlowDocument directly to a pdf using Microsoft Print to pdf. Each time I want to print it sets the printer to the last printer that was used, I need it to set to "Microsoft Print to PDF".

```
// Create a PrintDialog 
PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
// Create a FlowDocument dynamically. 
FlowDocument doc = CreateFlowDocument();
doc.Name = "OrderReceipt"+orderNo;
// Create IDocumentPaginatorSource from FlowDocument 
IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;
// Call PrintDocument method to send document to printer 
printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Save PDF");
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the default printer setting, which can be set to the last printer used:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028622/windows-10-how-to-set-a-default-printer

Comment: That's not the issue, I need to be able to set which printer it prints to as this will be running on various machines I won't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling PrintDialog.ShowDialog()?  It pops up the printer options and lets you select which printer to send to and set preferences.

```
// Create IDocumentPaginatorSource from FlowDocument 
IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;
// Display printer options
if( printDlg.ShowDialog() ?? false )
{
   // Call PrintDocument method to send document to printer 
   printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Save PDF");
}
```